# Are singleton classes in Rails shared across sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, singleton

In our application we are wanting to store some information on a Class that can be retrieved from this Class and we don't want to have to pass this information to the Class every time... we want to set it once and have it be available from that point onwards whenever we request that Class. This is because we want the Class to have state!

So we have looked into using a Singleton class to deal with this:

```
module ExampleModule
  class ExampleClass
    include Singleton

    attr_accessor :field_one, :field_two
  end
end
```

And then in our `ApplicationController` we do something like this:

```
instance = ExampleModule::ExampleClass.instance
instance.field_one = 'field_one'
instance.field_two = 'field_two'
```

Now anytime we do: `ExampleModule::ExampleClass.instance`

We can access those parameters that we set for the two fields without having to pass them back to the class which is what we wanted to achieve.

Our question however is... if User 1 hits our site and these values are then set... and then User 2 hits our site and we wanted different values for this class to be set for them... what would actually happen? Would it override the values of the instance for the other user? Or is this Singleton class kept separate between user sessions?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to store info that is available during multiple request, you need to keep it in a storage external to the Rails process. You have no guarantee that subsequent requests from the same user will be proxied to the same process (quite often it can be routed to a process living on another server). If you want to share data between requests, keep it in a database/redis/whatever storage with user session id as a key.

Comment: So we were trying to avoid using sessions due to them not being accessible within the class itself as sessions are only available from the controller and we didn't want to pass the session to the class every time as we have multiple parameters that need to be passed around. Seems that Singleton wouldn't be the correct solution here...thanks!

Comment: @Cameron this is a really common concern - to access request specific data from outside the controller without explicitly passing it as an argument. I've seen people use [thread variables](https://www.rubytapas.com/2016/11/20/ruby-thread-local-variables/) but this can also cause problems in shared environments like on worker servers, so I'd advise for simplicity's sake to just pass them as arguments somehow ..